# Почему в express 4 не работают суб-домены?

Tags: node.js, express

Сначала о структуре приложения. Файл `app.js` содержит конфигурацию основного приложения и двух под-приложений (admin,auth), выглядит он так:

```
//общие настройки
let app = express();
// настройка app

//настройки для админпанели 
let admin = express();
// настройка admin 

//настройки для под-приложения аутентификации
let auth = express();
// настройка auth 

//Здесь подключаем роуты:
require("router/root")({app:app,admin:admin,auth:auth});

//теперь под-приложение аутентификации будет доступно по адресу: localhost:3000/auth
app.use("/auth", secure);
//под-приложение админпанели вешаем на субдомен, должно быть доступно по адресу: admin.localhost:3000/
app.use(subdomain('admin', admin));

module.exports = app;
```

Теперь о роутах (подключали мы данный файл в `app.js` вот так: `require("router/root")({app:app,admin:admin,auth:auth})`):

```
module.exports = (options) =>{
    options.app.use('/', require('router/app/index'));
    options.app.use('/test', require('router/app/test'));

    options.admin.use('/', require('router/admin/index'));
    options.admin.use('/section', require('router/admin/section'));
    options.admin.use('/system', require('router/admin/system'));

    options.auth.use('/', require('router/auth/index'));
    options.auth.use('/logout', require('router/auth/logout'));
};
```

Ну и каждый подключенный роут выглядит примерно так:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", (req, res) =>{
   //TODO actions...
});

router.post("/my-url", (req, res) =>{
   //TODO actions...
});

module.exports = router;
```

**Теперь про проблемы:**

Для того чтобы организовать под-домен `admin.localhost` я использовал этот пакет: [express-subdomain](https://github.com/bmullan91/express-subdomain)

Но, до меня почему-то не доходит, почему когда я обращаюсь по адресу `admin.localhost:3000/` не срабатывает под-приложение для админ-панели, а выводится просто главная страница (основное приложение `app`). Получается что строка `app.use(subdomain('admin', admin));` совсем ничего не делает. В то же время, под-приложение auth, как и задумано, работает по адресу `localhost:3000/auth`.

Как мне заставить под-приложение `admin` работать по адресу `admin.localhost:3000/`? Или если есть вариант использовать другой пакет для организации суб-доменов - предложите.

**UPDATE**:

Проблема была решена, использовал другой пакет для обработки субдоменов: [линк](https://www.npmjs.com/package/subdomain)

Отсюда появилась проблема с куками, нужно как-то сделать кроссдоменную авторизацию, куки пишутся на основной домен `localhost` когда мы авторизуемся `localhost/auth/doLogin/`, но когда мы переходим на `admin.localhost` - получаем 403, т.к. у этого субдомена нет кук с данными юзера и сессия на него не распространяется. Как я использую куки:

```
app.use(subdomain({base:'localhost',removeWWW:true }));
app.use(session({
  secret:'mysecret',
  store: new redisStore({client: redis }),
  key:'skey',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: {
    path:"/",
    httpOnly:true,
    maxAge:null,
    domain:'.localhost'
  }
}));
```

Как пишутся куки:

```
res.cookie('ID',id, { maxAge: 1000000, httpOnly: true });
res.cookie('PASS',pass, { maxAge: 1000000, httpOnly: true });
```

Подскажите, как решить этот вопрос?

Comment: Думаю вам стоит подготовить [mcve]. Есть такое чувство, что из-за большого количества кода, не относящегося непосредственно к проблеме вы упускаете что-то важное.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, не думаю, т.к. этот код что есть можно сократить намного, он большой и в нем есть лишние части для того чтобы можно было понять как устроена конструкция. Я думаю дело конкретно в применении `subdomain`, но немогу понять так как не имел дела с ним ранее

Comment: По моему опыту, в 98% случаев, в сторонней библиотеке нет ошибки. Значит ошибка где-то в вашем коде. А раз так -- ее надо локализовывать (со всеми вытекающими). =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно поменять localhost на какой-нибудь другой домен и сессия будет распространяться на под-домены.